# [12728]:WARNING:android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:158:Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\User_Name\.android\emu-update-last-check.ini for reading

Tags: android, android-studio

on Android studio I keep getting this warning:

> [12728]:WARNING:./android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:158:Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\user_name.android\emu-update-last-check.ini for reading.

I have no idea what this means.

Answer (score 6):

On my machine, I was missing the `emu-update-last-check.ini` file for whatever reason.  I created an empty file in the folder listed in the message, named it `emu-update-last-check.ini`, and the error message went away.

**HOWEVER**, my emulator still did not start successfully, so there is another problem I need to track down.  I'm guessing that something didn't get installed correctly.  I'll post back here with a solution if I get it fixed.

**UPDATE** Once I checked the "Use Host GPU" checkbox the emulator started working for me.  I also played around with the amount of memory that the emulator was configured with. My current settings are RAM: 1024, VM Heap: 64, Internal Storage: 200 MiB, SD Card: Size 500 MiB.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help. I'll let you know as well if I figure out this problem.

Comment: Any luck, @TomasGallegos?

Comment: @TomasGallegos did this occurred inside Travis CI?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got the same log. I Switched from hardware to software for rending graphics.

[image: Virtual Device Configuration]

Answer (score 0):

If emulator is started, but your app didn't, try to uninstall your app on emulator manually and start it again, it will show errors in your app, in my case i had resources errors.